# Is it possible configure stunnel to accept any port

Tags: linux, stunnel

This is my stunnel conf located in /etc/network.d/stunnel.conf

```
[servertunnel]
accept=127.0.0.1:5001
connect=$server:5002
EOF
```

Here I want to change the port number to any port number. Because the port number is provided by the user.

I changed like this: It still works. I wondering is it legal to remove port address?

```
[servertunnel]
accept=127.0.0.1:5001
connect=$server
EOF
```

How to make `stunnel` to accept any port number?

I checked in net I didn't find much information about that, any help is appreciated?